# PHP: Why multiplying by "1E3" returns double and not int?

Tags: php, int, double, exponent, exponentiation

I have the following code:

```php
$waitTimeInMs = random_int(500, 1000);
// 1E3 = 10 to the power of 3 = 1000
echo gettype($waitTimeInMs) .'|'.gettype($waitTimeInMs * 1E3) . '|' . gettype($waitTimeInMs * 1000) .'|' . $waitTimeInMs * 1E3;
```

This returns `integer|double|integer|759000`.

So, practically:

- `random_int()` returns an `int`;
- Multiplying by `1E3` returns a `double`;
- Multiplying by `1000` returns an `int`;

**So, why multiplying by `1E3` returns a double and not an `int` if `1000 = 1E3`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponential  number are stored as double  .. because php don't change datatype for positive exponential or negative esponential

```
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php
```

the data type is the same for

```
$c = 7E-10;
```

or

```
$c = 7E+10;
```

but the first is tipically a float

Comment: Why storing them as float is better than storing them as integers?

Comment: because  storing a negative exponential  (es . 7E-3 =  0,003)  is not possible in an integer ..

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is false:

```
// 1E3 = 10 to the power of 3 = 1000
```

`1E3` is a short form of `+1.000E3`. It is per definition a floating point number in scientific computer notation:

```
// 1.23E4   => 1.23 * 10^4
// computer => scientific notation of a real number
```

btw: `0.123e5 === 1.23e4 === 12.3e3 === 123e2 === 12300e0 === 12300.0`